# ASUS P8B75-M Support Drivers incompatible with Win Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, asus

Hey I've just installed Windows Server 2003 Enterprise onto a newly built PC with this [motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8B75M/), but when I try to install the CDROM Support files it reports with an alert that says `"Support files incompatible with WIN... blah blah"` (Basically they seem to be only compatible with win7).

Should I be installing Windows Server 2012 for these drivers? or are there drivers that are compatible with the Server 2003 Operating System?

Comment: Avoid using old operating systems on new hardware.

Comment: Would Windows server 2012 be the best bet?

Comment: It would be a whole lot better, since you would actually be able to use the Windows 8 drivers for most or all of the hardware. If you really need Server 2003, virtualize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't install old Operating Systems. Let them Rest, and Rust, in Peace.

Do yourself and your profession a favor and install a version that's actually getting updates and isn't several years out of support from the vendor.

If you absolutely must run Server 2003, why run it on bare metal? Host it in a virtual environment such as VMWare ESXi or Hyper-V.

Comment: Thanks this, is actually a really point. Using vMware, at the time. We had to use Serv 2003; because AutoDesk Vault, wasn't compatible with 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Windows 7 and Server 2008/Server 2008 R2 are generally compatible with each other.  So, no, don't install Server 2012 expecting it to be compatible, as you may be disappointed; it's Server 2008/2008 R2 you're looking for here.

So, I'd install Server 2008 R2 in whatever edition you need, and frankly, do everything I could to avoid Server 2003, even as a Hyper-V VM.

Also, I'd advise avoiding Server 2012 and Windows 8 until SP1, particularly if this is in a professional (production) environment.  You need time to get familiar with the new platform, and waiting for the first major service pack also gives Microsoft time to fix the bugs and issues found by all the early adopters.

Don't get me wrong, I've got lots of it around in test and training environments, but I'm not about to put any actual business systems on it until it's mature enough, and I'm familiar enough with it that it's not begging for a catastrophe to do so.